# Unsure whether or not to use string or class

Tags: c#, string, class

What is the best way to store a series of integers together as a group and compare them to other groups of integers.  I am writing an RPG in C# as a class project and trying to write my own code.  I am only comparing 3 Stats, an Attack stat, a defense stat, and a speed stat.  I also have four Character classes.  each of which has the three stats.  Should I use separate classes for the character classes or will a string do me better for this?

Comment: If these are numbers then string is the worst choice. Use a `List<int>`

Comment: I vote use a Character class

Comment: how do you know @cricket_007? No code, don't assume! And why Character class?

Comment: Is there a reason I got down voted?  Is this not an appropriate question format or something?

Comment: use 3 different `int` properties, `Attack`, `Defense`, and `Speed`.  Storing the numbers in a string or even a list makes no sense.  Each number means something specific, why make it more complicated for yourself?  It sounds like you need a base `Character` class (or interface) with those 3 properties, then 4 classes that inherit `Character`

Comment: What do you think / why are you considering using a string vs using a class / some other data type or structure?  By thinking and then discussing you can learn; by only only asking you're unlikely to get much more than an answer to this specific question.

Comment: Because I am unsure if a string would actually work for what I am trying to do.  So i asked.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just hammer out what I was getting at in the comment.  Use a base `Character` class:

```
public abstract class Character
{
    public int Attack { get; set; }
    public int Defense { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
}
```

then, your classes will inherit `Character`.  E.g. a Mage would have low defense:

```
public class Mage : Character
{
    public Mage()
    {
        Defense = 1;
        Attack = 5;
        Speed = 5; 
    }
}
```

Always try to keep your code DRY

Comment: I'd avoid inheretance here. Such hierachies tend to get problematic in games. Instead, go with composition: `public class FighterStats { public int Health; … }`, then  `public class Mage { public FighterStats fighterStats; }`

Comment: My instructor was particular about not using classes due to the complexity of them.  My answer I was able to deduce is an even more simplified version of this.  Just using static ints instead of using classes.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to use classes in order to just assign different values to variables.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own even simpler method.  The complexity of classes is a bit beyond my skill barriers (For now I will have a coding class that will properly instruct us on the use of classes).  I came up with what I believe is probably the simplest and easiest answer to my problem.  Just using the stats as static ints for the player and then having readline just add or subtract what the stats actually are based on the ReadLine input using a While loop.

```
        {
            int GoblinKingHealth = 100;
            int GoblinKingAtk = 7;
            int GoblinKingDef = 0;
            int GoblinKingSpd = 3;
            int PlayerHealth = 100;
            int PlayerAtk = 0;
            int PlayerDef = 0;
            int PlayerSpd = 0;

            Console.WriteLine( "Chose your class." );
            Console.WriteLine( "Fighter" );
            Console.WriteLine( "Ninja" );
            Console.WriteLine( "Mage" );
            Console.WriteLine( "Knight" );


            while( true )
            {
                string line = Console.ReadLine();

                if( line == "Fighter" )
                {
                    PlayerAtk = +4;
                    PlayerDef = +4;
                    PlayerSpd = +2;
                    Console.WriteLine( "You have chosen the Fighter class.  The Fighter class is the most well balanced class with average attack and defense and slightly under average speed" );
                    break;
                }

                if( line == "Ninja" )
                {
                    PlayerAtk = +5;
                    PlayerDef = +2;
                    PlayerSpd = +4;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Ninja class.  The Ninja class is the fastest of the classes and has above average attack but a lower defense than the fighter.");
                    break;
                }

                if( line == "Mage" )
                {
                    PlayerAtk = +9;
                    PlayerDef = +0;
                    PlayerSpd = +3;
                    Console.WriteLine( "You have chosen the Mage class.  The Mage class has the strongest attack but the weakest defense and above average speed." );
                    break;
                }

                if( line == "Knight" )
                {
                    PlayerAtk = +1;
                    PlayerDef = +6;
                    PlayerSpd = +1;
                    Console.WriteLine( "You have chosen the Knight class.  The Knight class has near impenitrable defense at a heavy cost of speed and attack power." );
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: Using a static int on a `Player` would mean that any update to one player's ability would update every other's with the exact same value. From your own answer here, there are no `static` fields anywhere, i.e., `PlayerAtk` is an instance field on the class. More info: [static (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

Comment: Just remember for the future, that code like this is very bad. Code repetition, `while(true)`, which only looks like an infinite loop, variable naming and usage etc.